# How can I keep an active state to my nav elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I took inspiration on Ivan Grozdic's Hover slider and used it as a menu on my website. Everything works fine but I'm trying to keep the fill of the letter as an active state when someone is in that page. Here is the full code.

```js
(function($) { "use strict";
    // Page cursors
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].addEventListener("mousemove", function(n) {
        t.style.left = n.clientX + "px",
        t.style.top = n.clientY + "px",
        e.style.left = n.clientX + "px",
        e.style.top = n.clientY + "px",
        i.style.left = n.clientX + "px",
        i.style.top = n.clientY + "px"
    });
    var t = document.getElementById("cursor"),
        e = document.getElementById("cursor2"),
        i = document.getElementById("cursor3");

    function n(t) {
        e.classList.add("hover"), i.classList.add("hover")
    }

    function s(t) {
        e.classList.remove("hover"), i.classList.remove("hover")
    }

    s();

    for (var r = document.querySelectorAll(".hover-target"), a = r.length - 1; a >= 0; a--) {
        o(r[a])
    }

    function o(t) {
        t.addEventListener("mouseover", n), t.addEventListener("mouseout", s)
    }

    // Highlight active link
    const navLinkEls = document.querySelectorAll('.hover-target');
    const windowPathname = window.location.pathname;

    navLinkEls.forEach(navLinkEl => {
    const navLinkPathname = new URL(navLinkEl.href).pathname;
        if (windowPathname === navLinkPathname) {
            navLinkEl.classList.add('list-element');
        }
    });
              
    $(document).ready(function() {
        /* Hero Case study images */
        $('.slide-buttons li').on('mouseenter', function() {
            var index = $(this).index() + 1;
            $('.slide-buttons li.active').removeClass('active');
            $('.hero-center-section.show').removeClass("show");
            $('.hero-center-section:nth-child(' + index + ')').addClass("show");
            $(this).addClass('active');
        })
        $('.slide-buttons li:nth-child(1)').trigger('mouseenter');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
:root {
    --white: #ffffff;
    --black: #000000;
}

/* #Primary
================================================== */



::selection {
    color: var(--white);
    background-color: var(--black);
}
::-moz-selection {
    color: var(--white);
    background-color: var(--black);
}
mark{
    color: var(--white);
    background-color: var(--black);
}

.section {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    z-index: 30 !important;
}
.over-hide {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.hero-center-section{
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
    transition: all 300ms linear;
}
.hero-center-section.show{
    opacity: 1;
}


.z-bigger {
    z-index: 30 !important;
}

.img-wrap {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
    display: block;
    transform: scale(1.03);
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
    transition: all 300ms linear;
}

.img-wrap img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}

/* #Cursor
================================================== */
.cursor,
.cursor2,
.cursor3{
    position: fixed;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    pointer-events: none;
    left: -100px;
    top: 50%;
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
    transition: all 300ms linear;
    z-index: 9999999;
}
.cursor{
    background-color: var(--white);
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 9999999;
}
.cursor2,.cursor3{
    height: 36px;
    width: 36px;
    z-index:99998;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition:all 0.3s ease-out
}
.cursor2.hover,
.cursor3.hover{
    -webkit-transform:scale(2) translateX(-25%) translateY(-25%);
    transform:scale(2) translateX(-25%) translateY(-25%);
    border:none
}
.cursor2{
    border: 2px solid var(--white);
    box-shadow: 0 0 12px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
.cursor2.hover{
    background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}


/* #Menu
================================================== */
.list-element{
-webkit-text-fill-color: var(--white);
    text-fill-color: var(--white);
-webkit-text-stroke: transparent;
    text-stroke: transparent;

}

.slide-buttons{
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-right: 16px;
    list-style: none;
}
.slide-buttons li{
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
    transition: all 300ms linear;
}
.slide-buttons li a{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 96px;
    line-height: 1;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 2px var(--white);
    text-stroke: 2px var(--white);
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    text-fill-color: transparent;
    color: transparent;
    opacity: 0.5;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
    transition: all 300ms linear;
}
.slide-buttons li.active a{
    opacity: 1;
}
.slide-buttons li a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
}
.slide-buttons li a:focus,
.slide-buttons li a:active{
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
.slide-buttons li a::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 96px;
    line-height: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 0;
    max-height: 0;
    -webkit-text-stroke: transparent;
    text-stroke: transparent;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: var(--white);
    text-fill-color: var(--white);
    color: var(--white);
    content: attr(data-hover);
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.4s;
    transition: max-height 0.4s;
}


.slide-buttons li.active a::before,
.slide-buttons li a:active::before,
.slide-buttons li a:focus::before {
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hero-center-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="img-wrap">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1462889/nature.jpg" data-spai="1" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="hero-center-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="img-wrap">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1462889/art.jpg" data-spai="1" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="hero-center-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="img-wrap">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1462889/art.jpg" data-spai="1" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="hero-center-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="img-wrap">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1462889/art.jpg" data-spai="1" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="hero-center-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="img-wrap">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1462889/art.jpg" data-spai="1" alt="" data-spai="1" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="hero-center-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="img-wrap">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1462889/art.jpg" data-spai="1" alt="" data-spai="1">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="hero-center-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="img-wrap">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1462889/art.jpg" data-spai="1" alt="" data-spai="1" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="section padding-top-bottom over-hide z-bigger">
    <ul class="slide-buttons">
        <li class="">
            <a href="/page1" class="hover-target" data-hover="page 1">page 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a href="/page2" class="hover-target" class="hover-target" data-hover="page2">page2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a href="/page3" class="hover-target" data-hover="page 3">page 3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a href="/page4" class="hover-target" data-hover="page 4">page 4</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a href="/page 5" class="hover-target" data-hover="page 5">page 5</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a href="/page6" class="hover-target" data-hover="page 6">page 6</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a href="/page7" class="hover-target" data-hover="page 7">page 7</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<!-- Page cursor
================================================== -->

<div class='cursor' id="cursor"></div>
<div class='cursor2' id="cursor2"></div>
<div class='cursor3' id="cursor3"></div>
```

For that I'm using the window.location.pathname to check the current URL and add a class to the list element, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

```
const navLinkEls = document.querySelectorAll('.hover-target');
    const windowPathname = window.location.pathname;

    navLinkEls.forEach(navLinkEl => {
    const navLinkPathname = new URL(navLinkEl.href).pathname;
        if (windowPathname === navLinkPathname) {
            navLinkEl.classList.add('list-element');
        }
    });
```

Comment: I give up trying to use that navigation for testing its frustrating to use. Try being more specific in your CSS **.slide-buttons li a.list-element**

Comment: Sorry. I'm really stubborn with these little details. The menu works fine but I want (if possible) that little extra. I'm relatively new to code, can you be a little more specific? If anything, what should I do?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).